# Why composer.json requires PHP 7.4 but server is running PHP 7.3 doesn't break in deployment?

Tags: php, laravel, server, composer-php, forge

Our server is running PHP 7.3 but composer.json file requires PHP 7.4. We accidentally deployed to the server but it didn’t break. We are wondering if this is a cache issue or something else?  Can somebody share some lights here? We would like to know which potential parts prevent server crashing.

We are not able to run `composer install or update` manually to do some experiments because it is on production server. However, we have tried to reproduce in our local but it always break when we run `composer install`.

NOTE: We are using Forge to do deployment

Here is our deployment script

```
date
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force
npm install
npm run production
echo “” | sudo -S service php7.3-fpm reload
```

Here is our composer.json

```
{
    “name”: “laravel/laravel”,
    “type”: “project”,
    “description”: “The Laravel Framework.“,
    “keywords”: [
        “framework”,
        “laravel”
    ],
    “license”: “MIT”,
    “require”: {
        “php”: “^7.4|^8.0",
        “algolia/algoliasearch-client-php”: “^2.7",
        “algolia/scout-extended”: “^1.10",
        “backup-manager/laravel”: “^2.0",
        “ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package”: “v3.5.1.6",
        “cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable”: “^7.0",
        “davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs”: “^5.3",
        “doctrine/dbal”: “^2.11",
        “fideloper/proxy”: “^4.4",
        “fruitcake/laravel-cors”: “^2.0",
        “geoip2/geoip2”: “^2.9",
        “graham-campbell/markdown”: “^13.1",
        “guzzlehttp/guzzle”: “^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        “intervention/image”: “^2.5",
        “jenssegers/agent”: “^2.6",
        “jordanmiguel/laravel-popular”: “^1.0",
        “kyslik/column-sortable”: “^6.3",
        “laracasts/presenter”: “^0.2.1",
        “laravel/framework”: “^7.29",
        “laravel/passport”: “^9.3",
        “laravel/scout”: “^8.3",
        “laravel/tinker”: “^2.5",
        “laravel/ui”: “^2.0",
        “laravelcollective/html”: “^6.2",
        “laravelium/sitemap”: “^7.0",
        “league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3”: “^1.0",
        “mtownsend/read-time”: “^1.1",
        “otisz/laravel-imgix”: “^3.0",
        “renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed”: “^1.8",
        “sentry/sentry-laravel”: “^2.1",
        “spatie/dns”: “^1.4",
        “spatie/laravel-csp”: “^2.6",
        “spatie/laravel-permission”: “^3.17",
        “themsaid/forge-sdk”: “^2.2",
        “toin0u/geocoder-laravel”: “^4.1",
        “torann/geoip”: “^1.2",
        “tucker-eric/eloquentfilter”: “^2.3",
        “unisharp/laravel-filemanager”: “dev-master”
    },
    “require-dev”: {
        “barryvdh/laravel-debugbar”: “^3.5”,
        “laravel/dusk”: “^6.11”,
        “laravel/telescope”: “^3.5”,
        “laravel/tinker”: “^2.5”,
        “mockery/mockery”: “^1.3.1”,
        “nunomaduro/collision”: “^4.3”,
        “phpunit/phpunit”: “^8.5.8|^9.3.3”,
        “fakerphp/faker”: “^1.9.1”,
        “facade/ignition”: “^2.0”
    },
    “config”: {
        “optimize-autoloader”: true,
        “preferred-install”: “dist”,
        “sort-packages”: true,
        “platform”: {
            “php”: “7.4”
        }
    },
    “extra”: {
        “laravel”: {
            “dont-discover”: [
                “laravel/telescope”
            ]
        }
    },
    “autoload”: {
        “psr-4”: {
            “App\\“: “app/“,
            “Mpociot\\Versionable\\“: “packages/mpociot/versionable/src/Mpociot/Versionable/“,
            “CKSource\\CKFinderBridge\\“: “packages/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package/src/“,
            “CKSource\\CKFinder\\“: “packages/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package/_connector/”
        },
        “classmap”: [
            “database/seeds”,
            “database/factories”
        ]
    },
    “autoload-dev”: {
        “psr-4": {
            “Tests\\“: “tests/”
        }
    },
    “minimum-stability”: “dev”,
    “prefer-stable”: true,
    “scripts”: {
        “post-autoload-dump”: [
            “Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump”,
            “@php artisan package:discover --ansi”
        ],
        “post-root-package-install”: [
            “@php -r \“file_exists(‘.env’) || copy(‘.env.example’, ‘.env’);\“”
        ],
        “post-create-project-cmd”: [
            “@php artisan key:generate --ansi”
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it always break"? Your `composer.json` **requires** PHP 7.4, so why install it on the production server or change that requirement? Not running your production system on the same version than your development systems is not a good idea, as you will run in strange problems if there are incompatibilities between these two versions. Otherwise, if everything runs fine, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have older viersion of PHP in server it dosn't mean it always break the program.
But if Your program or Your dependencies used any [new features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php) or any [removed features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.removed-extensions.php) it will break. [in here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.php) you can see the differences between 7.3 and 7.4

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP 7.4 if composer.json requires this. If you don't want or not able to run composer install in the production server then at first try this in local and then deploy the source code to production.

Initially, your application may not throw any exception but there are lots of possibilities there are some features that will not work in PHP 7.3